# Enable swagger UI with custom 404 exception handler

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, swagger, swagger-ui

I want to disable default 404 handler in SpringBoot like:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(value = [NoHandlerFoundException::class])
    fun handleNotFoundException(e:NoHandlerFoundException):ResponseEntity<ApiError>{
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .body(ApiError("Resource not found"))
}
```

and be able to server swagger UI with api documentation on `/swagger-ui.html#`.

However, disabling default 404 handler requires setting 
`spring.resources.add-mappings=false` in `application-properties`, which also disables serving swagger UI. Is there a way to combine these two?

I am using `springboot:2.1.7` with `springox:swagger:2.9.2` and `springfox:swagger-ui:2.9.2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that by extending [`WebMvcConfigurer`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html) and add below method

```java
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
}
```

Note: Make sure your class annotated with `@configuration`

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented the swagger-ui along with custom exception handler. The way we are approaching is by parsing the swagger file of the api.

We have configured our swagger the by configuring @Bean of Docket which is also specified in this link: https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-restful-api-documentation-with-swagger-2/